# Unity3d actions when clicking an object

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, mouseover

I made a door opening script in unity That's the code of it:

```
void Update () {

    if (i < 5)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 1080);
            i++;

        }
    }
    else if (i >= 5)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 5400);
            i = 0;
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is that action take place when I click the mouse everywhere and everytime. I want to make it happen only when I click the door.

Comment: In duplicated answer, use *5.For 3D Object (Mesh Renderer/any 3D Collider)*

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [OnMouseDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) that uses the GameObject's collider.

Comment: Well, i made a void OnMouseDown(), and put isnide all the code instead of the void update, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: This script is attached to the door that has a collider component?

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty new to all this stuff and i dont understand too much of those. What is exactly the collides component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use raycasts to detect what object are you clicking, or you can use the Event OnMouseDown(), like:

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 1080);
}
```

OnMouseDown will not work on mobile devices